# How to calculate F1 Score for Multi-label Classification

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, classification

I am trying to calculate F1 score (and accuracy) for my multi-label classification problem. Could you please provide feedback on my method, if I'm calculating it correctly. Note that I'm calculating `IOU`  (intersection over union) when model predicts an object as `1`, and mark it as `TP` **only if** `IOU` is greater than or equal to `0.5`.

GT labels: `14 x 10 x 128` 
Output: `14 x 10 x 128`

where `14` is the `batch_size`, `10` is the `sequence_length`, and `128` is the object vector (i.e., `1` if the object at an index belongs to the sequence and `0` otherwise).

```py
def calculate_performance_metrics(total_padded_elements, gt_labels, predicted_labels):
        # check if TP pred objects overlap with TP gt objects
        TP_INDICES = (torch.logical_and(predicted_labels == 1, gt_labels == 1)).nonzero() # we only want the batch and object indices, i.e. the 0 and 2 indices
        TP = calculate_tp_with_iou() # details of this don't matter for now
        FP = torch.sum(torch.logical_and(predicted_labels, 1 - gt_labels)).item()
        TN = torch.sum(torch.logical_and(1 - predicted_labels, 1 - gt_labels)).item()
        FN = torch.sum(torch.logical_and(1 - predicted_labels, gt_labels)).item()
        return float(TP), float(FP), float(TN - total_padded_elements), float(FN)


for epoch in range(10):
    TP = FP = TN = FN = EPOCH_PRECISION = EPOCH_RECALL = EPOCH_F1 = 0.
    for inputs, gt_labels, masks in tr_dl:
        outputs = model(inputs) # out shape: (14, 10, 128)

        # mask shape: (14, 10). So need to expand it to the shape of output
        masks = masks[:, :, None].expand_as(outputs)
        
        pred_labels = (torch.sigmoid(outputs) >= 0.5).float().type(torch.int64) # consider all predictions above 0.5 as 1, rest 0
        pred_labels = pred_labels * masks
        gt_labels = (gt_labels * masks).type(torch.int64)
        total_padded_elements = masks.numel() - masks.sum() # need this to get accurate true negatives

        batch_tp, batch_fp, batch_tn, batch_fn = calculate_performance_metrics(gt_labels, pred_labels, total_padded_elements)
        EPOCH_TP += batch_tp
        EPOCH_FP += batch_fp
        EPOCH_TN += batch_tn
        EPOCH_FN += batch_fn

        EPOCH_ACCURACY = (EPOCH_TP + EPOCH_TN) / (EPOCH_TP + EPOCH_TN + EPOCH_FP + EPOCH_FN)
        
        if EPOCH_TP + EPOCH_FP > 0:
            EPOCH_PRECISION = EPOCH_TP / (EPOCH_TP + EPOCH_FP)

        if EPOCH_TP + EPOCH_FN > 0:
            EPOCH_RECALL = EPOCH_TP / (EPOCH_TP + EPOCH_FN)

        EPOCH_F1 = (2 * EPOCH_PRECISION * EPOCH_RECALL) / (EPOCH_PRECISION + EPOCH_RECALL)
```